# Postgresql Window function to get account log-in and account switching behavior

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Assuming the table as DDL below. Is there anyway to get the SQL query result below via window function?

More details on the output: trying to get the first log-in time of an account on a certain browser, until another one logged in later. In other words, trying to capture 'e12345' logging in on 2020-1-1 then 'e67890' logged in on the same browser on 2020-1-3. And then on 2020-1-5 'e12345' logged in again on browser '123'. Basically removing row number 2 and 4 from the original database.

```
create table timeline_log_in
    (date text,
    account_id text,
    browser_cookie_id text
    );

insert into timeline_log_in
    values
        ('2020-1-1','e12345','123'),
        ('2020-1-2','e12345','123'),
        ('2020-1-3','e67890','123'),
        ('2020-1-4','e67890','123'),
        ('2020-1-5','e12345','123'),
        ('2020-1-5','e67890','456'),
        ('2020-1-6','e12345','789');
```

Desired output:

```
-----------------------------------------
browser_cookie_id | account_id | date   |
-----------------------------------------
123               |e12345      |2020-1-1|
123               |e67890      |2020-1-3|
123               |e12345      |2020-1-5|
456               |e67890      |2020-1-5|
789               |e12345      |2020-1-6|
-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: I really can't understand the result you want, I don't see a pattern, can you describe it better?

Comment: Do you want to get first earliest date for each `account_id`?

Comment: Also, why do you have same two `account_id=e12345` for the same `browser_cookie_id=123`

Comment: `with t as (select *, account_id is distinct from lag(account_id) over (order by date) as account_switched from timeline_log_in) select * from t where account_switched;`

Comment: Sorry forgot to provide enough details on the output: trying to get the first log-in time of an account on a certain browser, until another one logged in later. In other words, trying to capture 'e12345' logging in on 2020-1-1 then 'e67890' logged in on the same browser on 2020-1-3. And then on 2020-1-5 'e12345' logged in again on browser '123'. Basically removing row number 2 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be defining groups based on `account_id` and `browser_cookie_id`.  Then, you want only the first row.  This  suggests `lag()`:

```
select tli.*
from (select tli.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by account_id, browser_cookie_id order by date) as prev_group_date,
             lag(date) over (order by date) as prev_date
      from timeline_log_in tli
     ) tli
where prev_group_date is null or prev_group_date <> prev_date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=403908814fc826c2347c9962d590eb01) is a db<>fiddle.